# WordPress won't let me change my administration email address

Tags: email

I'm trying to set my domain name email (something like `username@mywebiste.com`) to be the one that my website users can send messages to when they click on "send messages" on my website. I put my personal email for my administration email when I signed up for WordPress and now I want to change it to my domain name email. I went to WordPress Dashboard --> Settings --> General, I typed my domain name email and clicked on save changes and nothing changed. It still has my personal email as my admin email. How can I fix this?

Comment: Does WordPress show anything along the lines of 'this change will not be applied until the verification link in the email has been clicked'? You should get an email (on the new email address) containing a link where you can verify that you actually wanted to change your email address. After that, the administration email address will be changed.

Comment: You'll probably get an email sent to the original email for you to confirm the change. Check that first.

Comment: Or you can change it manually in the database to avoid the verification step

Comment: WordPress shows "This address us used for admin purpose. If you change this, we will send you an email at your new address to confirm it. The new address will not become active until confirmed". I checked my new email and the original personal email too. None. I was also told to install WordPress mail SMTP if nothing works. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

This method worked for me:

> **Change WordPress Admin Email without Verification (using a Plugin)**
>
> If you are unable to get the verification email to change the admin email address, then you can use this method.
>
> It basically allows you to bypass the WordPress verification and directly change the admin email address.
>
> First, you need to install and activate the [Change Admin Email](https://wordpress.org/plugins/change-admin-email-setting-without-outbound-email/) plugin. For more details, see our step by step guide on [how to install a WordPress plugin](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/step-by-step-guide-to-install-a-wordpress-plugin-for-beginners/).
>
> Upon activation, you need to visit the Settings » General page. Go to the ‘Administration Email Address’ option and enter the new email address you want to use.
>
> [image: change admin email address]
>
> Finally, click on the ‘Save Changes’ button to store your changes.
>
> The plugin will immediately change the admin address without verification. It will also send you a test email to the new admin email address.

*Source: https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-change-the-wordpress-admin-email/*